# if i have two models, model A and model B and i want the average of field of model A to be the value of a field in Model B

Tags: python, django, math, relationship, psql

I have two models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    truck = models.ForeignKey(Truck, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relation_truck',default=None)
    date= models.DateField()
    product=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    depot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    volume = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    volume_delivered = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

and anothe model:

```
class LoadingDashboard(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relation_loading',default=None,blank=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    loading_average = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    expect_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    loaded_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    remaining_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    total_trucks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    loaded_trucks=models.IntegerField()
    remaining_trucks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

i want to do some mathematical operations which is as follows:

1. the product in Model Loaded are only two: PMS And AGO
2. the product in Model Order is also PMS and Ago
3. trucks who are loaded with PMS in Model Order have specific volume which is 35000 and the volume_delivered should be a little bit short than 35000 for example 34294
4. trucks who are loaded with AGO have their specific volume which is 33000 and the volume_delivered can be for example 32294
5. i want the Field loading_average in Model Loaded to be the average of field volume_delivered with specified product be it AGO or PMS since they have different volume_delivered values divided by 1000
6. the expect_quantity in Model Loaded is given meaning i will decide the value
7. loaded_quantity in Model Loaded should be the sum of all the volume_delivered in Model Order with again PMS and AGO have diffferent volume_delivered so it should only do the sum of volume_delivered in Model Order for PMS if product is PMS and the same with AGO
8. remaining_quantity should be the difference of expect_quantity and  loaded_quantity
9. total_trucks should be the division of expect_quantity and loading_average
10. loaded_trucks should be the sum of the trucks in model Order and again there should be trucks with PMS and trucks with AGO. so loaded trucks if product is PMS in model Loaded should be sum of trucks with only product PMS in Model Order minus total_trucks for product PMS
11. remaining_trucks is the difference of loaded trucks and total_trucks.

what i have managed so far is :

```
def loading_dashboard(request):
# import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
loaded = LoadingDashboard.objects.all()
for math in loaded.iterator():
    if math.product == 'PMS':
        volume = list(Order.objects.filter(product='PMS')
        .values_list('volume_delivered', flat=True))
        order = volume
        sum = 0
        for volume in order:
            sum = sum + int(volume)
        return sum
        total = sum
        trucks = Order.objects.filter(product='PMS').count()
        loading = Order.objects.filter(product='PMS', order_status='Loaded').count()
        math.loading_average = total / trucks / 1000
        math.total_trucks = math.expect_quantity / math.loading_average
        math.loaded_quantity = total / 1000
        math.remaining_quantity = math.expect_quantity - math.loaded_quantity
        math.loaded_trucks = loading
        math.remaining_trucks = math.total_trucks - math.loaded_trucks
return render(request, 'loadings_dashboard.html' , {'loaded': loaded})
```

I am getting error 
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get' .

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have some example code?

Comment: i have posted what i have managed so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it after three days of research:

```
def loading_dashboard(request):
# import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

loaded = LoadingDashboard.objects.all()
for math in loaded:
    volume = list(Order.objects.filter(product='PMS')
    .values_list('volume_delivered', flat=True))
    order = volume
    sum = 0
    for volume in order:
        sum = sum + int(volume)

    trucks = Order.objects.filter(product='PMS').count()
    loading = Order.objects.filter(product='PMS', order_status='Loaded').count()

    volume_ago = list(Order.objects.filter(product='AGO')
    .values_list('volume_delivered', flat=True))
    order_ago = volume_ago
    sum_ago = 0
    for volume in order_ago:
        sum_ago = sum_ago + int(volume)

    trucks_ago = Order.objects.filter(product='AGO').count()
    loading_ago = Order.objects.filter(product='AGO', order_status='Loaded').count()
    if math.product == 'PMS':
        math.loading_average = sum // trucks // 1000
        math.total_trucks = math.expect_quantity // math.loading_average
        math.loaded_quantity = sum // 1000
        math.remaining_quantity = math.expect_quantity - math.loaded_quantity
        math.loaded_trucks = loading
        math.remaining_trucks = math.total_trucks - math.loaded_trucks
    elif math.product == 'AGO':
        math.loading_average = sum_ago // trucks_ago // 1000
        math.total_trucks = math.expect_quantity // math.loading_average
        math.loaded_quantity = sum_ago // 1000
        math.remaining_quantity = math.expect_quantity - math.loaded_quantity
        math.loaded_trucks = loading_ago
        math.remaining_trucks = math.total_trucks - math.loaded_trucks
return render(request, 'loadings_dashboard.html' , {'loaded': loaded})
```